# Magento 2.4.1 - 3D Secure with braintree (handling special chars)

Tags: magento2, 3d-secure

I've enabled 3D Secure within Braintree but I'm having an issue where if the name of the customer has special chars 3D Secure won't work.

I found this post online but I can't override find a way to pass the customer name and surname into brinatree without special chars, can anybody help please?

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/25483

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone facing the same issue, here is how we solved it :)

**app/code/vendor/module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
      config: {
            'PayPal_Braintree/js/view/payment/3d-secure': {
            'vendor_module/js/3d-secure': true        
          }
      }
  };
```

**app/code/vendor/module/view/frontend/web/js/3d-secure.js**

```
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
/*browser:true*/
/*global define*/

define([
    'jquery',
    'PayPal_Braintree/js/view/payment/adapter',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'mage/translate',
    'braintreeThreeDSecure',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/full-screen-loader'
], function ($, braintree, quote, $t, threeDSecure, fullScreenLoader) {
    'use strict';

    return function (target) {
        var validate = target.validate;

        target.validate = function (context) {
            var clientInstance = braintree.getApiClient(),
            state = $.Deferred(),
            totalAmount = parseFloat(quote.totals()['base_grand_total']).toFixed(2),
            billingAddress = quote.billingAddress();

            // No 3d secure if using CVV verification on vaulted cards
            if (quote.paymentMethod().method.indexOf('braintree_cc_vault_') !== -1) {
                if (this.config.useCvvVault === true) {
                    state.resolve();
                    return state.promise();
                }
            }

            if (!this.isAmountAvailable(totalAmount) || !this.isCountryAvailable(billingAddress.countryId)) {
                state.resolve();
                return state.promise();
            }

            // var firstName = this.escapeNonAsciiCharacters(billingAddress.firstname);
            // var lastName = this.escapeNonAsciiCharacters(billingAddress.lastname);
            
            var firstName = billingAddress.firstname.normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "");
            var lastName  = billingAddress.lastname.normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "");

            fullScreenLoader.startLoader();

            var setup3d = function(clientInstance) {
                threeDSecure.create({
                    version: 2,
                    client: clientInstance
                }, function (threeDSecureErr, threeDSecureInstance) {
                    if (threeDSecureErr) {
                        fullScreenLoader.stopLoader();
                        return state.reject($t('Please try again with another form of payment.'));
                    }

                    var threeDSContainer = document.createElement('div'),
                        tdmask = document.createElement('div'),
                        tdframe = document.createElement('div'),
                        tdbody = document.createElement('div');

                    threeDSContainer.id = 'braintree-three-d-modal';
                    tdmask.className ="bt-mask";
                    tdframe.className ="bt-modal-frame";
                    tdbody.className ="bt-modal-body";

                    tdframe.appendChild(tdbody);
                    threeDSContainer.appendChild(tdmask);
                    threeDSContainer.appendChild(tdframe);

                    threeDSecureInstance.verifyCard({
                        amount: totalAmount,
                        nonce: context.paymentMethodNonce,
                        billingAddress: {
                            givenName: firstName,
                            surname: lastName,
                            phoneNumber: billingAddress.telephone,
                            streetAddress: billingAddress.street[0],
                            extendedAddress: billingAddress.street[1],
                            locality: billingAddress.city,
                            region: billingAddress.region,
                            postalCode: billingAddress.postcode,
                            countryCodeAlpha2: billingAddress.countryId
                        },
                        onLookupComplete: function (data, next) {
                            next();
                        },
                        addFrame: function (err, iframe) {
                            fullScreenLoader.stopLoader();

                            if (err) {
                                console.log("Unable to verify card over 3D Secure", err);
                                return state.reject($t('Please try again with another form of payment.'));
                            }

                            tdbody.appendChild(iframe);
                            document.body.appendChild(threeDSContainer);
                        },
                        removeFrame: function () {
                            fullScreenLoader.startLoader();
                            document.body.removeChild(threeDSContainer);
                        }
                    }, function (err, response) {
                        fullScreenLoader.stopLoader();

                        if (err) {
                            console.error("3dsecure validation failed", err);
                            return state.reject($t('Please try again with another form of payment.'));
                        }

                        var liability = {
                            shifted: response.liabilityShifted,
                            shiftPossible: response.liabilityShiftPossible
                        };

                        if (liability.shifted || !liability.shifted && !liability.shiftPossible) {
                            context.paymentMethodNonce = response.nonce;
                            state.resolve();
                        } else {
                            state.reject($t('Please try again with another form of payment.'));
                        }
                    });
                });
            };

            if (!clientInstance) {
                require(['PayPal_Braintree/js/view/payment/method-renderer/cc-form'], function(c) {
                    var config = c.extend({
                        defaults: {
                            clientConfig: {
                                onReady: function() {}
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    braintree.setConfig(config.defaults.clientConfig);
                    braintree.setup(setup3d);
                });
            } else {
                setup3d(clientInstance);
            }

            return state.promise();
        }

        return target;
    };
});
```